# do something 'before' login in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I am pretty new to loopback and here is what I am doing:

I am using standard login route provided by the loopback to log in the users - extended base Users to my own model say orgadmin.

With prebuilt route /api/orgadmin/login, I can easily login.

Now, I have a flag in orgadmins say 'status' which can be either 'active' or 'inactive' based on which I have to defer user login.

I was thinking something with remote hooks like beforeRemote as below but it doesn't work:

```
//this file is in the boot directory
module.exports = function(orgadmin) {
    orgadmin.beforeRemote('login', function(context, user, next) {
        console.log(user)
        // context.args.data.date = Date.now();
        // context.args.data.publisherId = context.req.accessToken.userId;
        next();
    });
};
```

So what is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

The `user` attribute will only be available if the request is coming with a valid access token. The attribute is unused for unauthenticated requests, which `login` is.

Here's a possible alternative:

```
module.exports = (OrgAdmin) => {
  OrgAdmin.on('dataSourceAttached', () => {
    const { login } = OrgAdmin;
    OrgAdmin.login = async (credentials, include) => {
      const accessToken = await login.call(OrgAdmin, credentials, include);
      const orgAdmin = await OrgAdmin.findById(accessToken.userId);
      if (orgAdmin.status !== 'active') {
        OrgAdmin.logout(accessToken);
        const err = new Error('Your account has not been activated');
        err.code = 'NOT_ACTIVE_USER';
        err.statusCode = 403;
        throw err
      }
      return accessToken;
    };
  });
};
```

The above code overrides the `login` method and does the following:

1. Login the user, using loopback's built-in login
2. Take the response of `login`, which is an access token, and use it to get the user.
3. If the user is active, return the access token, satisfying the expected successful response of `login`.
4. If the user is not active, remove the access token that was created (which is what `logout` does), and throw an error.

Comment: Hey thanks! This syntax: Orgadmin.on('dataSourceAttached'.... has any docs? Are they called events on models? what other events apart from 'dataSourceAttached' are available...sorry lots of questions :)

Comment: `dataSourceAttached` is documented under "[Model events](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Events.html#model-events)" and here's an example customizing [`find`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Customizing-models.html#via-your-models-script). You need to override any [`PersistedModel`](http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#persistedmodel) methods after `dataSourceAttached` is emitted. However, now that you brought this up, I am seeing that `login` is not part of `PersistedModel`, but instead [`User`](http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#user). So, `dataSourceAttached` is not required here.